# How to work with optionally nested resources and cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have resources that can optionally be accessed through another resources, like so

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
resources :tasks
```

If tasks are accessed through project, I want to render some project-related info, and that is pretty much all the difference.

However, I use cancan and need to authorize all the things so in TasksController I write

```
load_and_authorize_resource :project
load_and_authorize_resource :task, through: :project
```

but this breaks functionality when we don't nest tasks.

How can I solve this elegantly?

My first thought was to use two controllers instead of TasksController and share all the common things using concerns but that's kind of messy (at least I would have to explicitly specify views).

Another approach I can think of is to authorize things manually instead of using cancan helpers.

Are there some other ways?

Comment: In my opinion, you should handle authorization over data manually.
Which will just need simple if condition. Using cancan here might complicate the solution. I prefer simpler the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd limit the routes that can be accesible without the project scope:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
resources :tasks, only: :index
```

Then you might call the cancan helper method for the rest of actions and handle the custom loading and authorizing on the index method:

```
class TasksController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource :project, except: :index
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, through: :project, except: :index

  def index
    authorize! :index, Task
    if params[:project_id].present?
      @project = Project.find(params[:project])
      authorize! :show, @project
      @tasks = @project.tasks.accessible_by(current_ability)
    else
      @tasks = Task.accessible_by(current_ability)
    end
  end
```

Note: if you want to handle new/create/edit/update actions for both resources, it will require custom views and will be easier with two controllers.